# Software for drawing roads and bridges

Tags: software-recommendation

Is there an application that runs on Ubuntu that I can use for drawing roads and bridges?

Comment: This is a request for software recommendation which is typically not suitable for askUbuntu forums. You also have not specified what kind of software is suitable for Roads and Bridges use. Paint could fit the bill, but I suspect what you actually want is a CAD package. Try LibreCAD or Blender for 3D modelling.

Comment: @taifwa software recommendations are OK if they are specific and detailed. I think your answer is on-point though.

Answer (score 4):

If you've used Auto CAD before, then FreeCAD and LibreCAD would work

- [FreeCAD](https://www.freecadweb.org/) or [LibreCAD](http://librecad.org/cms/home.html) - Computer Aided Design software
- [Blender](https://www.blender.org/download/) - 3D modelling software
- Scroll down the list of [alternatives to AutoCAD](https://alternativeto.net/software/AutoCAD/?platform=linux)